# What are the elements of metric space?Is it always an interval are it can be set of integers etc.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

What are the elements of metric space? Is it always an interval or it can be set of integers, etc.?

Comment: It can be any non-empty set.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The definition I know doesn't exclude the empty set either.

Answer (score 2):

An metric space can, as mentioned above, be any non-empty set. Hence, the elements of a metric space can be almost anything you can imagine, as long as you can equip that set with a metric. A metric is intuitively a way to measure the distance between elements. Here are some examples:

**Example 1: $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric.** The elements are in this case vectors $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ and the metric is

$$d(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \rVert = \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^n (x_1-y_1)^2 \bigg)^{1/2}.$$

**Example 2: The discrete metric.** Let $X$ be a non-empty set. We can make it a metric space by endowing it with the discrete metric, given by

$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
0, \quad & x = y \\
1, \quad & x \neq y 
\end{cases}.$$

**Example 3: The vector space of continuous real-valued functions on $[a, b]$.** Consider the vector space $C([a, b])$ of continuous functions $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$. We can give it with the following metric:

$$d(f, g) = \bigg( \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \, dx \bigg)^{1/2}.$$

Notice that in these three examples, the elements of the metric spaces are different objects. Mind you that a set can often be equipped different metrics and still be a metric set. For example are the metrics I have used in example 1 and 2 not the only metrics compatible with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C([a, b])$.

Answer (score 0):

A metric space is an **arbitrary** non-empty set $X$, together with a metric, i.e., a map $d\colon X\times X\to\Bbb R$ with the appropriate properties.